# golang function with leading "type ***"

Tags: go

```
type ApplyFunc func(commitIndex uint64, cmd []byte) []byte
```

For this declaration. My understanding is,this is a function pointer. Its name is ApplyFunc. 
And this function takes commitIndex and cmd as inputs. It returns []byte.

Is my understanding right?
thanks!

Comment: Almost, just two misconceptions: First `ApplyFunc` is a type (a named type) and not a function or a pointer to a function. Variables of type ApplyFunc will be functions. Second: It is not a "pointer" (not even a pointer type). To get a pointer you need something to point to, e.g. by `var af ApplyFunc = func(uint64,[]byte) []byte {return nil}` and then taking the address `afp := &af`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Golang function are first-class, as illustrated in this [go-example page](https://golang.org/doc/codewalk/functions/).

It is a **[named type](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations)**, which means you can use `ApplyFunc` anywhere where a `func(commitIndex uint64, cmd []byte) []byte` is expected: see "[Golang: Why can I type alias functions and use them without casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19334952/6309)".

It means, as commented by [Volker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1266756/volker), it isn't a function or a "pointer to a function".
It is a **type** which allows you to declare a variable storing any function which respects the same func signature as its declared type, like a [function literal](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals) (or "anonymous function").

```
var af ApplyFunc = func(uint64,[]byte) []byte {return nil}
                 // (function literal or "anonymous function")
```

See "[Anonymous Functions and Closures](http://cplus.about.com/od/google-go/a/programming-golang-tutorial-on-anonymous-functions-closures.htm)": you can define a function which returns another function, taking advantage of closure:

> Function literals are **closures**: they may refer to variables defined in a surrounding function.
>   Those variables are then shared between the surrounding function and the function literal, and they survive as long as they are accessible.

(see [playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/qNU_JQ5cjz))

```
type inc func(digit int) int

func getIncbynFunction(n int) inc {
    return func(value int) int {
        return value + n
    }
}

func main() {
    g := getIncbynFunction
    h := g(4)
    i := g(6)
    fmt.Println(h(5)) // return 5+4, since n has been set to 4
    fmt.Println(i(1)) // return 1+6, since n has been set to 6
}
```

---

Also, As illustrated in "[Golang function pointer as a part of a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20729726/6309)", you can define functions on a func receiver `ApplyFunc`(!).

Comment: thanks. Go really includes so many syntax features than c++ or C.

Comment: @NoName regarding c/c++ syntax, see also (on another topic) the new blog post http://blog.golang.org/constants